# Altium Footprint has a huge room than the footprint itself

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, footprint

I have a problem regarding footprint clearance or something similar while using Altium 18.1.11. The problem occurred as I designed a Pad with via on it but when I imported it to the PCB doc, the part has a huge room that is larger than the footprint itself and Altium did not allow me to place them properly. I have tried looking at the Footprint by using "Find Similar Object" but only the Pad and the vias are in the Footprint as I thought there might be another object in the footprint that caused this issue.[image: PCB project with pad error][image] Thank you in advance!

Comment: turn on the other layers, there's most likely some artifact on a different layer that is causing this.

Comment: You probably can't place it becuase those vias are assigned different nets than your circuit (or no net at all).   Altium won't let you create short-circuits between nets.  The solution may be to click on each via in your pad, assign the right net to it.   .....  Maybe   ;)